# radio button value not hold in edit form if validation error occur

Tags: php, forms, validation, mysqli, radio-button

I am using a radio button option in edit form. In edit form radio button checked depend from data base value.for this I am using

```
<input type="radio"  name="active" value="active" <?php echo ($row['service']=='active')?'checked':'' ?>> Active
<input type="radio"  name="active" value="deactive" <?php echo ($row['service']=='deactive')?'checked':'' ?>> Deactive
```

its working fine.but in edit form if anyone change this value and submit the form and he remain any validation error of other field then radio button again reset to old value.how can i kept this value.

Ex. In a user edit form deactive radio button selected from database value , then  user change this button to active and edit in mobile no field also and submit the form .if there are any validaton error in mobile no field then radio button also selected previousd(deactive).how can i kept them unchanged?

my form code is

```
<?php include_once 'header.php';
$ra=$_SESSION['ra']
$sql="SELECT * FROM emitra_basic where uid='$ra'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(isset($_POST['update'])) 
     {$phone = $_POST['cno'];
     //validion example 
       if(strlen($phone)!=10) {
       $flag=1;
       $phoneErr = "Not a valid phone number";}.......like this other validaiton
   //then insertion..
    my form code are......
   <form id="basic" method="post" name="basic"  >
   <p class="contact"><label for="RU">service</label></p>               
    <input type="radio" id="active" name="active" value="active" <?php echo ($row['service']=='active')?'checked':'' ?>/> Active
    <input type="radio" id="active" name="active" value="deactive" <?php echo ($row['service']=='deactive')?'checked':'' ?>/> Deactive
    <p class="contact"><label for="contct No">Contact No</label></p> 
    <input id="cno" name="cno" placeholder="Contact No" value ="<?php  if(isset($phone)){ echo $phone; }elseif($phoneErr=="") {echo $row['contact'];} ?>" type="text">
```

I am tried also using this

```
<input type="radio" name="active" value="active" <?php if (isset($active) && $active=="active") echo "checked"; elseif($row['service']=='active') echo "checked"; ?> > Active
            <input type="radio"  name="active" value="deactive" <?php if (isset($active) && $active=="deactive") echo "checked"; elseif($row['service']=='deactive') echo "checked"; ?> > Deactive
```

but no result found.
Its working fine in normal condition but in form updation any validation error occur then radio button checked again as to database value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (($_POST['active']) == 'active') {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?>
```